# C# Parallel.For but with a double as the parameters

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, double

So, I have a for loop that I'm trying to parallelise, but this for loop takes in a double as the parameter, and for some reason C# hates this. I cant just cast it as an integer because when i do it gives me out of bounds error and isn't as accurate. Is there any possible way around this? or a different parallelising method i could use.

This is the original for loop:

```
for (ii = 0; ii < 2 * Math.Floor((double)N / (double)wSamp) - 1; ii++)
{
   \\Code is added here
}
```

And this is what i have so far for it (gives me an error):

```
Parallel.For(0, 2 * Math.Floor((double)N/(double)wSamp) - 1, ii => {
    \\Code is added here
});
```

Comment: What is the type of the `ii` variable?

Comment: What error it produces?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you ask to run loop 3.14 times? It is very unclear what exactly you want to achieve with `double` for number of iterations and it is really hard to do "exclusive" bounds with non-integer values...

Answer (score 1):

Because the Parallel.For can only accept integers in the first two fields. The Parallel. For is not an actual for loop. It is a function call as part of the Parallel class.

See the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netcore-3.1

In particular  look at the parameter definitions. This is from the 64bit int overload.
Parameters
fromInclusive
Int64
The start index, inclusive.

toExclusive
Int64
The end index, exclusive.

body
Action
The delegate that is invoked once per iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the output of `Floor` to `int`:

```
Parallel.For(0, 2 * (int)Math.Floor((double)N/(double)wSamp) - 1, ii => {
    \\Code is added here
});
```

If you know `N` and `wSamp` have the same sign, you can even remove the `Floor`:

```
Parallel.For(0, 2 * (int)((double)N/(double)wSamp) - 1, ii => {
    \\Code is added here
});
```

I do not know what the types of `N` and `wSamp` are, but is they are `int`, you can also consider using the built-in overload of `operator /` which takes two `int`s and returns an `int` result:

```
Parallel.For(0, 2 * (N / wSamp) - 1, ii => {
    \\Code is added here
});
```